# Unanticipated visual elements present in the raster image generated via its SVG counterpart

Tags: c#, xamarin, svg, skiasharp

An unanticipated amount of dregs is present in the background of the PNG images (as seen in the following images) generated from their SVG counterpart (attached to the app as an embedded resource) using the `SkiaSharp` libraries for use in `Button` and `ToolbarItem` views.

At a cursory glance, I believe that the issue pertains to the way the PNG image is generated from the SVG but, as of now, am unable to isolate the portion causing this "improper conversion" as I cannot segregate the problematic portion in the implementation of the `GetEquivalentBitmapImagePath()` method (shown below).

[image: ToolbarItem with the problematic image]

Code that generates the above entity:

```
string calculationHistoryIcon = GetEquivalentBitmapImagePath
                          (CALCULATION_HISTORY_ICON_RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER,
                           80, 80);
ToolbarItem calculationHistoryToolbarItem = new ToolbarItem()
                { IconImageSource = calculationHistoryIcon };
this.ToolbarItems.Add(calculationHistoryToolbarItem);
```

[image: Button with the problematic image]

Code that generates the above entity:

```
string fullKeypadIcon = GetEquivalentBitmapImagePath
                        (FULL_KEYPAD_ICON_RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER,
                         50, 80);
Button keypadBtn = new Button()
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
};
keypadBtn.ImageSource = fullKeypadIcon;
```

The following method is used to generate the PNG image:

```
private string GetEquivalentBitmapImagePath
        (string embeddedVectorIdentifier,
         float widthOfBitmapImage,
         float heightOfBitmapImage)
{
    // For converting vector (.svg) images to raster images
    SKSvg svg;
    SKBitmap bitmap;
    SKCanvas canvas;
    SKImage image;
    SKData encodedData;
    Stream imageStream;

    string vectorImageFile;
    Stream embeddedResourceStream;
    FileStream vectorImageStream,
               bitmapImageStream;
    string bitmapImagePath;

    if (widthOfBitmapImage < 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value passed", "widthOfFinalImage");
    if (heightOfBitmapImage < 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value passed", "heightOfFinalImage");

    try
    {
        vectorImageFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, embeddedVectorIdentifier);
        embeddedResourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(embeddedVectorIdentifier);
        vectorImageStream = new FileStream(vectorImageFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        embeddedResourceStream.CopyTo(vectorImageStream);
        embeddedResourceStream.Flush();
        vectorImageStream.Flush();
        embeddedResourceStream.Close();
        embeddedResourceStream.Dispose();
        vectorImageStream.Close();
        vectorImageStream.Dispose();

        svg = new SKSvg(new SKSize(widthOfBitmapImage,
                                   heightOfBitmapImage));
        svg.Load(vectorImageFile);
        bitmap = new SKBitmap(Convert.ToInt32(svg.CanvasSize.Width),
                              Convert.ToInt32(svg.CanvasSize.Height));
        canvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap);

        canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture);
        canvas.Flush();
        canvas.Save();
        image = SKImage.FromBitmap(bitmap);
        encodedData = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
        bitmapImagePath = vectorImageFile.Replace(".svg", ".png");
        bitmapImageStream = File.Open(bitmapImagePath,
                                      FileMode.Create,
                                      FileAccess.Write,
                                      FileShare.None);
        encodedData.SaveTo(bitmapImageStream);
        bitmapImageStream.Flush(true);
        bitmapImageStream.Dispose();
        File.Delete(vectorImageFile);
        return bitmapImagePath;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @jdweng To remove the aforementioned unwanted dregs from the image of course.

Comment: The results is only as good as the resolution of the image output.  So how are you determining the resolution?  See following code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: @jdweng The example in the link you posted is irrelevant as the aforementioned question as it deals with the SkiaSharp library rather than the standard .NET System.Drawing namespace. Besides, if you are referring to the quality of the image by the word resolution, it is set to maximum in the ```Encode()``` method in ```GetEquivalentBitmapImagePath()```.

Comment: How is the image resolution being set in your code?  The link show ways of getting better resolution.

Comment: @jdweng Are you suggesting that I amplify the resolution of the image generated from the SVG by the SkiaSharp library using the ```Image.Save()``` method as described in the aforenoted link?

Comment: No, just the resolution of the new image used to create the new png.  The Net library will take current image and convert to the to resolution of the new png.  So if the default resolution of the png is less than the original image you will loose resolution.  I've seen code that take original image and then searches the graphic card library to set the new resolution.

Comment: @jdweng Can you provide a simple example to implement your last suggestion? The .NET library you suggested regarding image encoders is unfortunately unsupported in the Xamarin platform as seen in the ```Applies To``` section in the bottom of the link you suggested (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#moniker-applies-to).

Comment: @hecate Hi, have you tried with the method from [this discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/120364/how-to-use-svg-images-for-xamarin-forms)?